# High voltage high speed low current amplifier

Tags: amplifier, high-frequency

I want to design an amplifier that can take an 8MHz signal (even square) with an amplitude of only a few volts (1-3V) and amplify it up to 160V but I only need it to deliver about 60mA. I also want to avoid using a high voltage input voltage.

Does anyone have any ideas where to start? I was thinking of a small class A amplifier in conjunction with a transformer. Would the use of a transformer be impossible due to the high frequency? Or should I just use a boost converter and then use it to supply my class A/class AB amplifier?

Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Have you computed the slew-rate this is going to require? (You write "even square" and this could imply a rather fast edge.)

Comment: It's not going to be a perfect square as that is impossible (infinite slew-rate). But for a triangular wave at 8MHz I would need about 4800V/us, Am I right? (for a 150V output from zero)

Comment: Could I maybe use something like this? I don't mind the floating output. http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva516/snva516.pdf

Comment: The very first sentence in that datasheet says it has +/- 40 V maximum power supply, so that won't get you to 160 V.

Comment: At page 3, there is a proof of concept circuit using 2 of those ICs in parralel to drive a floating load. (130V Drive Across a Floating Load) But the slew rate is bad, 6V/µs. It is no where near what I need.

Comment: @CezarChirila That example is 130 V "peak to peak". That's the total excursion. And it's based upon using the entire \$\pm 35\:\text{V}\$ output swing capability of two devices. You aren't clear in your writing, but I'd normally take your 160 V and think you mean "peak" and not "peak to peak." Either way you answer, that part won't get there by itself (added parts could help, though.)

Comment: @CezarChirila For slew-rate, I'd start with assuming a sine wave and not a triangle. If your specification is \$160\:\text{V}_\text{PK}\$ I get about \$8000\:\frac{\text{V}}{\mu\text{s}}\$. If it is \$160\:\text{V}_\text{PP}\$ then half that or about \$4000\:\frac{\text{V}}{\mu\text{s}}\$. And this number goes rapidly up for anything even starting to look a little squarish.

Comment: My bad, it is 160V Peak-to-Peak. Thank you for answering. So what do you think, should I head in this direction, using discrete / ICs and a high voltage power supply? Or using a simple amplifier and a transformer on the output, such as this example here: http://sound.whsites.net/articles/line-amps-f12.gif ? I'm used to low frequency electronics / digital circuitry.

Comment: Also how can I improve the slewrate of a high voltage amplifier? Using a separate input stage?

Comment: @CezarChirila The slew rate of a BJT input opamp is completely determined by the 1st stage quiescent current and its pole-splitting capacitance. I don't believe added stages are of any utility in getting better slew rates. You *may* get higher GBW adding stages. But not increased slew-rate, so far as I understand it. Assume a quiescent 10 mA for the 1st stage alone, I get that you still need (much) less than 2.5 pF of pole-splitting capacitance.

Comment: If you need a square wave of a fixed amplitude, forget about amplifiers, switch a 160V supply instead. Fast enough switching is challenging enough.

Comment: @CezarChirila For an ideal BJT 1st stage, I believe there exists a relationship between GBW and slew-rate. I think it works out to \$SR=\frac{I_\text{q}}{C_\text{splitting}}\$ and \$GBW=SR\cdot\frac{1}{4\:V_T}\$. (No, I do NOT want a long debate saying SR and GBW are at best loosely related. I'm discussing an ideal 1st stage, central to slew rate. There is an appnote somewhere on this topic, memory serving.) Best wishes on finding this to be an easy achievement. I think you'll spend some time on this problem.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Unfortunately I need triangle, square and sinusoidal. But your idea is not bad, I could just make a simple separate circuit for that. It shouldn't be hard, just some mosfets with small gate charge and a discrete driver.

Comment: @jonk thank you for your help! I'll look into that direction

Comment: @CezarChirila Just as a start, look at CFBs like the THS3096 and VFBs like the LM7171. I don't know how you will add discretes to get the additional closed-loop voltage swing and current compliance. I'd love to learn from a good answer here. So I'll +1 to see if it gets any traction from my betters.

Answer (score 1):

As an overall approach, I would start at the high level solution architecture first, then progress to the specifics and exact components.

In this case, you need up to a 160 x amplification of a 1v p-p HF (high frequency) RF signal.  8 MHz is radio frequency. 160 v p-p RF brings with it some other challenges around RFI / EMI that need to be considered (you didn’t explain how this 160V RF signal is to be used).

160 x amplification is 40 dB of gain.  You will need at least a couple of amplification stages.  This sounds similar to “linear amplifiers”, where one would begin with a Class A single transistor amp stage, followed by a Class AB push-pull stage.  Then there’s the matter of matching the input and output impedances, properly biasing each stage and ensuring no RF gets back up into your power supply with proper filtering.

At the low current levels you need, it shouldn’t require highly expensive power transistors as you’re only talking 10 watts output. With efficiency in the 60%+ range you can probably do fine with 20 watt finals in the PA.

That’s how I’m framing out a potential solution based on the limited requirements available at this stage.

PCB layout and shielding will also need some consideration, along with your power supply.